# What is "family of overloaded indexers" in CLR/C#?

Tags: c#

I am reading "Framework Design Guidelines" book and I am puzzled by one of the rules (p.142) "Do not provide more than one family of overloaded indexers in one type."

I know how the overloaded indexer looks like, but what makes a family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [the lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229061(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Some compilers, such as the C# compiler, enforce this guideline.
>
> Multiple sets of indexers are not supported by some languages. If you use them, some developers will not be able to access these members.

I assume it means "do not provide indexers with different names in one type". A family of indexers would be a set of overloaded indexers with the same name.

Comment: Do indexers have names?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis In VB they do, yes.

Comment: Thank you, so each family is grouped by a name that stands before brackets, in case of C# it is always `this`. In such case C# does more than this, because you cannot even specify the family, am I correct?

Comment: @greenoldman Yup, C# doesn't support more than the "default" family... which is both the reason for this rule and the reason you can ignore it if you're a C# developer.